# List within a List - How to put new line with LinQ after List within List is over?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List inside List.
As you can see from my foreach example, I go through flights first, and then through SEGMENTS, I print all segments from 1 flight in 1 line, only then I put NewLine for new flight, which can consist from 1 segment, or more segments. 1 Segment consist of departure time and arrival time.

When I use **foreach** I can put new line after each segment is finished, like this:

```
foreach (var flight in f)
{
    foreach (var flight1 in flight.Segments.Where(x=>x.DepartureDate > DateTime.Now))
    {
        Console.Write(
            "Departure: {0}, Arrival: {1}; ",
             flight1.DepartureDate,
             flight1.ArrivalDate);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Result:

> Departure: 2.9.2013 12:23:05, Arrival: 2.9.2013 2:23:05;
>
> Departure: 2.9.2013 12:23:05, Arrival: 2.9.2013 2:23:05; Departure:
>   2.9.2013 3:2 3:05, Arrival: 2.9.2013 5:23:05;

This works nice. I am now interested how could I make this with Linq? I have my results with Linq, but all results are in one line, don't know where to put "NewLine" to put each flight segment into new line instead of all segments in one line... If I use Environment.NewLine, it will put each segment in new line. But segments from 1 flights should be in 1 line.

I use this Linq method:

```
public IEnumerable<Segment> GetActiveFlights(IEnumerable<Flight> flights)
{
    var query = from flight in flights
    from segment in flight.Segments
    where segment.DepartureDate > DateTime.Now
    select new Segment()
    {
        DepartureDate = segment.DepartureDate,
        ArrivalDate = segment.ArrivalDate
    };
    return query;
}
```

I use this to iterate then:

```
IEnumerable<Flight> f = flightList.GetFlights();

foreach (var flight in flightFilter.GetActiveFlights(f))
{
    Console.Write(
        "Departure: {0}, Arrival: {1}; ",
        flight.DepartureDate,
        flight.ArrivalDate);
}
```

Result:

> Departure: 2.9.2013 12:23:05, Arrival: 2.9.2013 2:23:05; Departure: 2.9.2013 12:
>   23:05, Arrival: 2.9.2013 2:23:05; Departure: 2.9.2013 3:23:05,
>   Arrival: 2.9.2013  5:23:05; Departure: 2.9.2013 12:23:05, Arrival:
>   1.9.2013 6:23:05; Departure: 2.
>   9.2013 12:23:05, Arrival: 2.9.2013 2:23:05; Departure: 2.9.2013 5:23:05, Arrival

But here all my results are in one line. How can I make that each flight(which consist of multiple segments or 1) is written in new line.

Comment: How about using console.writeline which makes newline by default?

Comment: This makes each segment into new line, which is not what I need, because some flights could be made from multiple "segments"(for example if it's not direct flight to the destination, if you have to move to other plane... For example you fly from Venice to Philadelphia and than from Philadelphia to San Francisco. And I need whole flight(built from segments) in 1 line as you can see from foreach example.

Comment: It will only get weirder with LINQ. You have to do some operations while iterating the elements, LINQ is ideal for querying. Your nested foreach implementation is perfectly fine in this situation I think.

Comment: I just thought It would be better practice and better readability if you use linq or lambda expression instead of double foreach.

Comment: After renaming `f` and `flight1` variables to something more intuitive, this piece of code seems readable enough to me. Also, performance-wise, I don't think you can do any better than this.

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.Write(
    String.Join(Environment.NewLine, f.Select(flight => {
        var segments = flight.Segments.Where(x => x.DepartureDate > DateTime.Now);
        return String.Join("  ", segments.Select(segment => {
            return String.Format("Departure: {0}, Arrival: {1};", segment.DepartureDate, segment.ArrivalDate));
        });
    });
);
```

I personally prefer to have a `Joined` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` which wraps `String.Join` (taking a delimiter and an optional transformation delegate), and a `Formatted` extension method on `String` which wraps `String.Format`:

```
var output = 
    f.Joined(Environment.NewLine, flight => 
        flight.Segments
              .Where(s => s.DepartureDate > DateTime.Now)
              .Joined("  ", s => "Departure: {0}, Arrival: {1};".Formatted(s.DepartureDate, s.ArrivalDate))
    );

Console.Write(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = flights.SelectMany(f=>
                   new []{ string.Join("", f.Segments
                                 .Where(s=>s.DepartureDate > DateTime.Now)
                                 .Select(s=>
                                   string.Format("Departure: {0}, Arrival: {1}; ", s.DepartureDate, s.ArrivalDate))), Environment.NewLine});
foreach(var e in query)
  Console.Write(e);
```